# Edit code during build of gradle in android studio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, edit

Can I edit the code while the Gradle build is running in Android Studio?
Could those changes be taken into consideration or break the build or does it make a copy before compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the gradle configurations during a build, but you should not expect that these edits take effect during that build.  The only way to be 100% certain that your changes to build files are being used is to kick off a new build *after* the changes have been made.

Comment: Ok, that's what I actually do, but thanks for confirming =)